# Pushbullet API: Delete Chat method returns Object not found

Tags: pushbullet

I receive a list of chat identifiers using `/v2/chats` endpoint.

When I try to delete a chat found in that list using the `/v2/chats/{iden}` endpoint I always receive a Object not found error.

My request:

```
curl --header 'Access-Token: TOKEN' --request DELETE  https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/chats/IDENTIFIER
```

The Response:

```
{
    "error" : {
        "code":"invalid_request",
        "type":"invalid_request",
        "message":"Object not found",
        "cat":"(^人^)"},
        "error_code":"invalid_request"
    }
 }
```

This occurs with any chat identifier I try to use.

The "hide" chat menu item in the app (Android) does not remove the chat either.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this request and it seems to work fine.  If you delete a chat which has already been deleted you get that error though.

Comment: It seems the problem is that creating a chat does not mark it as "active".
I need to send a message first in order to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Chat using the `/v2/chats` endpoint creates a chat that shows up when doing a `list-chats` call. However the chat is not marked as active and therefore it is not deletable until you send a message in the chat.

Comment: I just created a chat with /v2/chats and then deleted it and there were no errors.